# How to filter Postgres query results based on specific inner json element values?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table with the following structure:

| id | values |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | {"something":{"insideSomething":{"tables":{"tableA":{"include":false},"tableB":{"include":true}}}}} |

I would like to output a list of tables where "include" is true.

Ideal results would look like this:

| id | tables |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | (tableB,”{“”include””: true}") |

I am able to use the following query in order to output results where each table is in its own row, bundled with the value contents (I do not mind that there are potentially multiple rows for each id).

select id, json_each(values::json#>'{something, insideSomething, tables}') as tables from myTable;

Is there a good way to filter these results to only include those which match my criteria? Any help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below uses a recursive `cte` to walk the deeply-nested `json`. This has the added benefit of being able to handle arbitrarily-nested and named objects

```
with recursive cte as (
   select t.id, null parent, t1.key, t1.value from tbl t cross join jsonb_each(t.js) t1
   union all
   select c.id, c.key, t1.key, t1.value from cte c 
   cross join jsonb_each(case when jsonb_typeof(c.value) = 'object' then c.value else '{}'::jsonb end) t1
)
select * from cte where key = 'include' and value = 'true'::jsonb
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yLXDS49P)

Comment: I know this is out-of-scope from the original question, but I am joining to another table on id which also has a list of tables - and I need to find the overlap of tables in table2 that have included: true on table1. I am also parsing json in table2 but its not nested. Any ideas?

Comment: @user17331277 can you post a sample of your `table2`? It might be as straightforward as a simple `join` on the `id` and table name with a filter on the inclusion value.